# Convert multiple rows to one row

Tags: postgresql, row

```
select 
    datum, naam, 
    to_char(verkocht::numeric/(verkocht+beschikbaar)*100, 'fm00D00%') rangen 
from 
    (select 
         sr.namenl rang,
         count((case when t.currentstatus is null   then '1' end)) as beschikbaar, 
         count((case when t.currentstatus = 101   then '2' end)) as verkocht,
         coalesce(e.namenl) || ' ' || coalesce(e.subtitlenl,'') naam,
         e.startts datum,
         sr.id seatrank
     from 
         tm.ticket t
     inner join  
         tm.tickettype tt on tt.id = t.tickettypeid
     inner join 
         tm.event e on e.id = tt.eventid
     inner join 
         tm.seatrank sr on sr.id = tt.seatrankid
     where 
         e.id = 28744 
     group by 
         1, 4, 5, 6
     order by 
         1 desc) sq1
group by 
    1, 2, 3
```

Current result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KPOi.png)

What I would like is to convert the 4 row result into 1 row. The 4 different outcomes in row "rangen" next to each other so that I have 1 row with 6 columns. Don't know if this is possible and I am fairly new to this as you can see :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg` function. For example, like as this query:

```
select 
    datum, naam, 
    string_agg(rangen, ', ') as rangen 
from table 
group by 
    datum, naam
```